# React : What is the best practice for using both Typescript and PropTypes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I am looking for the best way to use both Typescript and PropTypes in React.

First of all, I understand that both serve different purpose:

- Typescript : static type checking during compilation.
- Proptypes : type checking during runtime.
  I want to use both.

As a first attempt, I tried to implement both indenpendtly :

- using typescript types to declare types
- using PropTypes to declare PropTypes
  Simple I thought.... but no.
  I had several issue with incompatible PropTypes and Typescript types.
  It seems typescript typing is more precise.
  Even if I could find a match between Typescript/Proptypes in some case, it introduces unecessary complexity.

On a second attempt, I tried to use  PropTypes.InferProps<*component.propTypes*>. as follow :

```
const propTypes = {
    a: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    b: PropTypes.exact({
        innerpropA: PropTypes.number,
        innerpropB: PropTypes.string,
    }),
};
const MyComponent: FC<PropTypes.InferProps<typeof propTypes>> = ......

MyComponent.propTypes = propTypes;
```

It works, but I am worried that this process is losing in type precision and seems to degrade the typing.

Now I am confused. Did I choose the wrong way to do this?

According to your experience, what is the best way to use both Typescript and PropTypes efficiently?

### Best Regards

Fred